# A div 'infront' of a div?

Tags: php, css, html, stylesheet

I'm trying to code a design I've just made: http://www.richardhedges.co.uk/brlan/design.jpg

I'm pretty much done coding but the only thing I don't know how to do is the footer overlapping the main content. What I'd like it to do is scroll the content. (Like it is on Facebook messages)

The footer is simply a div with nothing in it:

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

And here's the stylesheet:

```
div.footer {
    width: 980px;
    height: 114px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../images/footer.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I need to create a new div which I'll include the content in (as shown in the design.JPG) however it must be 'behind' the PNG image in the footer. I've absolutely no idea how I'd do this - My apologies for ignorance.

Comment: Surely you don't expect us to download your zip file, decompress it, and sort through your entire code base, do you? Please select the relevant code snippets and post them here.

Comment: A testcase would be better than a behemoth of a ZIP file.

Comment: I must apologies, I am sorry I didn't realise before posting it. But now reading your comments I look like an ignorant sod. I'll edit my main post and add the code there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 9001;
}
div#content {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Missed your answer. Sorry. Up-voting.

Comment: Thanks LaC.
I assume the scrolling will have to be Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the votes!@Richard: no, the footer's position is fixed relative to the content, so it will scroll with it.

Comment: I've set the footer to not scroll what so ever. The reason for this is because I want the content div to scroll through what it has, and everything else stay still. Very much like Facebook Messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning and a higher z-index on the footer div than on the ones it'll be in front of.